# Logging file is not created

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, log4j2

I use log4j2 in my eclipse plugin for logging. I created the following log4j2.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="trace">
    <Appenders>
        <File name="File" fileName="MyLog.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </File>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="File" immediateFlush="true"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I can see the logs in the console, but the log file seems not even to be created. In the mean time, I'm quite desperated. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with the configuration file. If you are using eclipse to test log file will get generated in root folder of the project. You may want to use fileName="target/MyLog.log" or absolute file path to  to move file to anticipated folder.

Comment: I agree this is very likely what's happening. What do you see if you use an absolute path?

Comment: When I use an absolut path, the logger is loaded without an exception, but the file is not created.

Comment: Did you figure out the issue? I cant believe this configuration has any issue even after creating a file.